# Cannot update status on page property using notion api

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api

I am trying to update the status of a page using the api. I am using the JS-sdk built by notion.

To update the status you have to update the properties-object.
I cannot get it to work as expected, it always throws an error.

I have tried to use the name of the property ('Status') and I have tried to use the id of the property but the same error appears.

```
const response = await notion.pages.update({
    page_id: 'abc123',
    properties: {
        [statusProp.id]: {
            status: {
                title: 'Done'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
{
object: 'error',
status: 400,
code: 'validation_error',
message:
    'body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.properties.bSYl.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\r\nbody.properties.bSYl.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.bSYl.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
```

}

Their [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-value-object#status-property-values) says: `Not currently editable.`.
Although I am unsure whether they mean only the property 'color' of the status-property or if they mean the status-property.
[Image of their doc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPGIH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'title' to 'name'.